# Doctrine mapped field is not working

Tags: php, doctrine

I have two entities `User\User` and `Misc\Notification` and I want to have the possibility to fetch the user's notifications inside the User entity, by doing `$user->getNotifications()`.
Usually I have no problem with this type of relations.

See my code below (I just added the TicketApp relation as an example, since this relation works and is exactly the same):

#### `User\User : properties`

```
/**
 * This is working
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="[...]\Entity\Ticket\TicketApp", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $tickets;

/**
 * This is not
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="[...]\Entity\Misc\Notification", mappedBy="receiver", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
private $notifications;
```

#### `User\User : __construct()`

```
$this->tickets       = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
$this->notifications = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

#### `Misc\Notification : properties`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="[...]\Entity\User\User", inversedBy="notifications")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $receiver;
```

---

This seems to be Ok (or maybe this evening I'm completely blind...).
The problem is : `$user->getNotifications()` returns `null` instead of a Doctrine `Collection` object.
I have datas in my table. This type of code works and returns two notifications:

```
$em->getRepository('[...]:Misc\Notification')->findByReceiver($user);
```

Also, I noticed in the Symfony debug toolbar that **no query is fired** when using `$user->getNotifications()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was despairing of finding a solution when I remembered that Doctrine have its proper cache, independent from Symfony (I tried tens of `cache:clear` without any change).
I thought that my problem could be a Doctrine cache issue, so I tried to clear the cache:

```
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

(If you are using Doctrine standalone, this command has its equivalent in pure Doctrine, Symfony just renames and improves Doctrine commands).

If you have a normal installation, this should work, otherwise continue to read.

In a normal time, in dev mode at least, Doctrine regenerates the metadata cache at each request. But Doctrine also have an APC interface to store its cache... I activated it two or three weeks ago, and I have completely forgotten it. When I ran the command above, Doctrine said:

```
Cannot clear APC Cache from Console, its shared in the Webserver memory and not accessible from the CLI.
```

The problem is clear now. Doctrine fills the cache and then can't remove data correctly. The `getNotifications` method was returning `null` because  it was pure PHP, but Doctrine had no knowledge that the `notifications` property was SQL-mapped. So the field were never initialized. If you use another cacher, that's probably a similar issue.

The error given above is self-explaining. You'll need to clear the APC datastore. Since it is hosted by the webserver process, just reboot this guy:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Amen.